# Publishing ASP.NET Core WebApp

Tags: asp.net-core, teamcity, dotnet-cli

I have a WebApp built using `ASP.NET 2.2` and using `TeamCity` to deploy it. My build steps are as follow

[image: TeamCity build steps]

When I check the publish directory I can see that the `wwwroot` folder is missing. For my own sanity I did a `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` (Visual Studio is not used) on my local version and I can see that the wwwroot is being copied to the publish folder.

Why there is a difference in the behaviour and what should I do please to make sure that this works?

**As a side note: I am using `bundleconfig.json` and `gulpfile.js` and all content are copied fine locally.**

On my local machine I have `Visual Studio 2019 v16.3.8` plus the below

[image: Installed .NET Core versions]

On TeamCity I am using `.NET Core SDK v2.2.402`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first I still don't know why when running the `dotnet publish` command locally it works and on TeamCity it doesn't, but here how I fixed my issue:

1. I installed [BuildBundlerMinifier](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/) to process `bundleconfig.json`.

> That NuGet package contains an MSBuild task that will run the exact same compilers on the bundleconfig.json file in the root of the project.

2. I added a step to run `gulp` manually.